# LinearModelFit[ ] and missing data

Tags: fitting

I have a data set where there is a lot of missing values; they are labelled `Missing["Non-mesuré"]`. When I append this data to another list of same length which has no missing data, and try to fit a line to those two lists with `LinearModelFit[]`, I get the following error message:

```
LinearModelFit::notdata: The first argument is not a vector, matrix, or a list containing a design matrix and response vector.
```

I get that `Missing["Non-mesuré"]` is not data, but isn't the point of `Missing[]` to allow for missing values?

Here is a sample of the data:

```
data={{2.2,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{1.8,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{1.8,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{1.7,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.1,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.1,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{1.8,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.2,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.2,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.2,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.5,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.1,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.1,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.1,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.3,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.3,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{1.7,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.1,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{1.7,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{1.8,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.1,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{2.1,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{1.5,0},{1.5,0},{1.7,0},{1.1,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{3,0},{1.6,0},{2.1,0},{1.7,0},{1.8,0},{1.7,0},{1.6,Missing[Non-mesuré]},{1.5,0},{2.2,0},{2.3,0},{2.3,0},{1.9,0},{1.9,0},{1.9,0},{1.3,0},{1.9,0},{1.9,0},{1.9,0},{1.9,0},{1.9,0},{1.3,0},{1.9,0},{1.9,0},{2,0},{2,0},{2,0},{2,0},{1,0},{1.4,0},{1.9,0},{1.8,0},{1.7,0},{1.5,0},{2,0},{2,0.333333},{2,0.25},{2.2,0.0208333},{1.7,0},{1.7,0},{1.7,0.0416667},{1.7,0},{2,0},{2,0},{1.7,0},{2.3,0},{1.7,0},{1.7,0.0138889},{1.7,0},{1.7,0.0208333},{2,0},{1.7,0},{2.4,0},{1.7,0},{0.5,0},{2,0},{1.7,0},{1.7,0.0416667},{1.7,0.0138889},{1.7,0.0208333},{2.1,0},{1.7,0},{2.1,0.0104167},{3.4,0.0208333}}
```

And here is the code I first tried:

```
LinearModelFit[data,x,x]
```

I also tried to remove the data points that contained missing values, without success:

```
LinearModelFit[If[#[[2]]==Missing["Non-mesuré"],Nothing,#]&/@data,x,x]
```

So either it is possible to make the fit work with the missing data, or there is a way to exclude it when doing the fit. Either solution would brighten my day.

Comment: Missing sometimes work with functions but a fit is not one of those cases. You couold interpolate these points but this undermines the task of Fitting. So we just want to delete them. You can Easily do it with patternmatching with DeleteCases: `DeleteCases[data,{_Missing,_}|{_,_Missing}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. What kind of functions, then, is Missing[ ] compatible with?

Comment: `Missing` seems to be mostly for use in `Association`s, for returning missing values from Wolfram's curated data like `CountryData` or `ElementData`. It seems to be compatible with visualization tools like `ListLinePlot`. Otherwise, I suspect it's not useful. It's certainly unlikely to be useful for numerical functions and calculations.

Comment: I see, it's true that I did not have any problems with `ListLinePlot` or even `DateListPlot`.

Comment: Prior to Missing you could run into issues with dummy data or uncertainty if data wasn't there, hadn't been uploaded or that your query wasn't adequately formed. Missing makes it easier to manipulate using a known form:

Comment: So you can use something like:`Sort@data /. {x_, Missing[_]} -> {x, -1.} or {__, Missing[_]} -> Nothing`

Comment: Or something like `LinearModelFit[Select[data, #[[2]] != "Missing[Non-mesuré]" &], x, x]`.

Comment: another approach a bit more general: `Cases[data, {_?NumericQ ..}]`. This will also strip `Indeterminate` , undefined symbols and so on.